# Yii CGridView column values are not able to access by $data->time. getting error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, yii-components, cgridview

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'mobile_no',
    'dataProvider' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'header' => 'Name',
                'name' => 'emp_name',
            ),
            array(
                'header' => 'Track Id',
                'name' => 'mobile_no',
                'value' => '$data->time',// Issue. $data['time']; is working fine.
            array(
                'header' => 'Date&Time',
                'name' => 'time',
            ),      
        'address',
        'Accuracy',
            array(
                'header' => 'GPS Location',
                'name' => 'isSpecialLog',
               // 'urlExpression'=>'"users/view&id=".$data->isSpecialLog',
            ),  

    ),
));
```

Please suggest how to solve this issue? Issue is $data['time'] is working fine but $data->time is showing error getting error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: To access data as shoown in yii frame work im using $data->time. This is giving error. but $data['time'] working fine. How can i solve error for $data->time access

Comment: Are you using in your model dataProvider CArrayDataprovider or  CSqlDataProvider? Both use associative array  to data access as you describe, instead of object access